# python how to parse "user:12345 location:ny search"

Tags: python

I want python to parse string ""user:12345 location:ny search"

Then I can use:

```
if "user" in string:
....

if "location" in string:
...
```

Any existing way to do this?

Comment: Parse it to what? What is the expected output?

Comment: You actually can already do `if "user" in string:` with a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the original version of unutbu's answer was impressive, now `re` seems a bit overkill. Here is a simpler one:

```
>>> text = 'user:12345 location:ny search'
>>> dict(pair.split(":") for pair in text.split() if ":" in pair)
{'user': '12345', 'location': 'ny'}
```

**Edit:**

To insert `"search"` with key `"keyword"`:

```
>>> dict(([] if ":" in pair else ["keyword"]) + pair.split(":") for pair in text.split())
{'user': '12345', 'keyword': 'search', 'location': 'ny'}
```

Comment: can I get 'keyword':'search'?

Answer (score 0):

There might be a better way to do it, but this is what I came up with:

```
mydict = {}
for pair in mystring.split(' '):
    parts = pair.split(':')
    if len(parts)>1
     mydict{parts[0]:parts[1]
```

But this implies that nor dict keys, nor values can contain spaces. Separating the pairs by comma's might solve this problem.

The optimal thing to do would be to encode and decode them as json, which would make it look like this:

user:{'user_id':1234,'location':'my search'}

the standard python libraries contain a [json encoding and decoding lib.](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html)

Answer (score 0):

a simple straightforward solution if string is always in that format:

```
if string.find('user:') > -1:
    user = string[string.find('user:' + len('user:'):string.find('location:') - 1]
    ....
if string.find('location:') > -1:
    location = string[string.find('location:') + len('location:')]
    ...
```